# inserting ORM Table not callable

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, crud

Using sqlacodegen I produced a model, of which the following was produced:

```
t_exception = Table(
    'exception', metadata,
    Column('exception_id', Integer, nullable=False),
    Column('load_id', ForeignKey('metadata.load.load_id')),
    Column('exception_msg', String(collation='French_CI_AS')),
    Column('exception_date', DateTime),
    schema='metadata' )
```

I am trying to insert a record into the exception table.

```
error = meta.t_exception(load_id= load_id, exception_msg= message, exception_date = exception_date)
```

and since its not an instance of Class(Base) I am getting this error:

> Exception has occurred: TypeError, 'Table' object is not callable

Is there something wrong with how the table got generated, and if not how can I perform CRUD operations on this table?

Comment: That's a Core `Table` and you can see how they're used here: https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/tutorial.html

Comment: Why did sqlacodegen make this a core table and not a class?

Comment: It doesn't seem to have a primary key.